# In OpenApi, can I use the info.version as a default parameter elsewhere in the document?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am writing an API spec in Open API.
I would like the paths to include their version as a parameter; this way, if there is a version change in the future, the implementing code could identify which version it was called with.
So far, so good.

What I would like is for the version of the API doc to be the default version in the path's version parameter.
Something like:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: JXG API
  version: 1.2.3

servers:
  - url: https://jxg.info/api

paths:
  /jxg:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: X-Version
          schema:
            type: string
            default: <info.version>
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK.
```

Is there a way to get `info.version` into the `default` of the parameter schema?
I've looked at the documentation, and couldn't find anything in either direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `$ref` keyword to reference the definition should work fine:

```
schema:
  type: string
  default: 
    $ref: '#/info/version'
```